# RowNum behavior

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have 6442670 records in a table and i am fetching them using 
**jdbctemplate** 1000000 at a time using row number.
The following is the query

```
select * 
from (select rowNum rn
             , e.* 
      from table_name e) table_name  
where rn >= ? and rn <= ?
```

I am fetching in eight iterations

> - 0 to 1000000
> - 1000001 to 2000001
> - 2000002 to 3000002
> - 3000003 to 4000003
> - 4000004 to 5000004
> - 5000005 to 6000005
> - 6000006 to 7000006
> - 6442669 to 7442669

After eight iterations I see only 6442668 records in list, and most of this are duplicate.
Can fetching records using rowNum fetch the same record multiple times?

Comment: You have no `order by` so the rows returned in each iteration are arbitrary.

Comment: It works on few database and doesnt work on other database

Comment: Am wondering why is it having different behavior in different database

Comment: Maybe because someone has deleted some rows whilst you've been running the queries?

Comment: Maybe order by all the columns in the table in the sub select. Then the rownum will always be the same. Identical rows my have different row numbers but that won't matter since they are identical.

Comment: *"it works on few database"* - I think you misunderstand what the word *arbitrary* means...

Answer (score 1):

Try using `row_number() over` unique columns instead of `ROWNUM`.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY unique_column_s ) rn,  e.*
          FROM table_name e ) table_name
 WHERE rn >= ? and rn <= ?
```